# How to update a base map to get a better image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, basemap

I want to use a base map under some layers I'm working on. It's in an island in Azores, Portugal. I need one World Imagery so It can be seen all the vegetation, buildins and streets. My problem is that those maps have a big flaw right in the place I need. You can see it in the picture. How can I fix it?

[image]

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

You may download the image section you need from

http://glcf.umd.edu/data/

http://landsat.usgs.gov/

https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/high_res_ortho

The downloaded image-subsets should be rectified.

Also you could use SASPlanet, a software to view and download georeferenced images of high resolution satellite maps.